# How to update a file on Perforce shelf using p4v?

Tags: perforce

A file (opened for edit) is already on a shelf, I then made more local changes, and want to update the file on the shelf. What is the best way to do this via the GUI P4v?

Comment: duh, that was obvious. Thanks, I could not find the shelf menu at the file level, thus the silly question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p4 shelve -c  -f

Will force update the entire changelist. This will overwrite the previous version of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Shelving the changelist again achieves the goal.